# CWWKE0070W: The loose file \xxx.xml is invalid

Tags: java

While trying to deploy in PCF, Liberty server ear.xml is not packaging as a list of jar files. Also, it throws an error as `CWWKE0070W`: The loose file `C:\Projects\Liberty Server\Test Server\servers\test-wlp\apps\reservation.xml is invalid.`